# how to remove backspace key bug

Tags: c#

please run the given code and go to "Editor mode"

by doing this, you will notice "backspace bug" if you type any word of syntax highlight list

if you  write  this and try to remove the previous written word in previous line

[image]

then you will face the bug

I am unable to remove the syntax highlighted words with arrow in the given program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool isInEditorMode = false; // Track if we are in editor mode
        static Dictionary<string, ConsoleColor> highlightColors = new Dictionary<
            string,
            ConsoleColor
        >();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "SCRIPTER - Version 1.01";
            // Add your desired word-color mappings to the highlightColors dictionary
            highlightColors.Add("samip", ConsoleColor.Blue);
            highlightColors.Add("srijan", ConsoleColor.Blue);
            highlightColors.Add("regmi", ConsoleColor.Red);
            highlightColors.Add("<html>", ConsoleColor.DarkBlue);
            highlightColors.Add("</html>", ConsoleColor.DarkBlue);
            highlightColors.Add("<head>", ConsoleColor.Blue);
            highlightColors.Add("</head>", ConsoleColor.Blue);
            highlightColors.Add("<title>", ConsoleColor.Red);
            highlightColors.Add("</title>", ConsoleColor.Red);
            highlightColors.Add("<body>", ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
            highlightColors.Add("</body>", ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
            highlightColors.Add("<table>", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
            highlightColors.Add("</table>", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
            highlightColors.Add("<marquee>", ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
            highlightColors.Add("</marquee>", ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);

            Console.Clear();
            string input;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    @"▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
██░▄▄▄░██░▄▄▀██░▄▄▀█▄░▄██░▄▄░█▄▄░▄▄██░▄▄▄██░▄▄▀███▀███▀█▀░█████░▄▄░█▀░██
██▄▄▄▀▀██░█████░▀▀▄██░███░▀▀░███░████░▄▄▄██░▀▀▄████░▀░███░██▀▀█░▀▄░██░██
██░▀▀▀░██░▀▀▄██░██░█▀░▀██░██████░████░▀▀▀██░██░█████▄███▀░▀█▄▄█░▀▀░█▀░▀█
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀"
                );
                Console.WriteLine(
                    @"
                .---------.
                | samTime |
                '---------'
"
                );

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Enter E to enter editor mode, I to open a file, or Q to quit the program."
                );
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input.ToUpper() == "E")
                {
                    isInEditorMode = true;
                    EditorMode();
                    isInEditorMode = false;
                }
                else if (input.ToUpper() == "I")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the path of the file to open: ");
                    string filePath = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                        isInEditorMode = true;
                        EditorMode(text);
                        isInEditorMode = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine(filePath + " doesnot exist");
                    }
                }
                else if (input.ToUpper() == "Q")
                {
                    break; // Exit the while loop and terminate the program
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void EditorMode(string text = "")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Editor mode. Press Ctrl+S to save, Ctrl+X to exit.");
            int topMargin = Console.CursorTop;
            int leftMargin = Console.CursorLeft;
            int currentLine = topMargin;
            int currentPosition = leftMargin;

            Console.Write(text);
            currentPosition += text.Length;

            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
            do
            {
                keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

                // Check if we are in editor mode before processing the key
                if (isInEditorMode)
                {
                    if (
                        keyInfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control && keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.S
                    )
                    {
                        Console.Clear(); // Clear the console screen
                        SaveFile(text);
                        return; // Exit the EditorMode method
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && currentPosition > leftMargin)
                    {
                        currentPosition--;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                        Console.Write(" ");
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                        if (text.Length > 0)
                        {
                            text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (
                        keyInfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control && keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.X
                    )
                    {
                        Console.Clear(); // Clear the console screen
                        return; // Exit the EditorMode method
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow && currentPosition > leftMargin)
                    {
                        currentPosition--;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                    }
                    else if (
                        keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow
                        && currentPosition < Console.WindowWidth - 1
                    )
                    {
                        currentPosition++;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && currentLine > topMargin)
                    {
                        currentLine--;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                    }
                    else if (
                        keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow
                        && currentLine < Console.WindowHeight - 1
                    )
                    {
                        currentLine++;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    {
                        text += Environment.NewLine;
                        currentLine++;
                        currentPosition = leftMargin;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                    }
                    else if (char.IsControl(keyInfo.KeyChar))
                    {
                        // Ignore control characters
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        text += keyInfo.KeyChar;
                        Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
                        currentPosition++;
                    }

                    // Check if any highlighted words are present in the text and apply
                    // the corresponding colors
                    foreach (var highlight in highlightColors)
                    {
                        string word = highlight.Key;
                        ConsoleColor color = highlight.Value;
                        int index = text.IndexOf(word);
                        while (index >= 0)
                        {
                            int line = topMargin + text.Substring(0, index).Split('\n').Length - 1;
                            if (line == currentLine)
                            {
                                int lineStartIndex = text.LastIndexOf('\n', index) + 1;
                                int column = index - lineStartIndex;
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(leftMargin + column, currentLine);
                                Console.ForegroundColor = color;
                                Console.Write(word);
                                Console.ResetColor();
                            }
                            index = text.IndexOf(word, index + word.Length);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                }
            } while (true);
        }

        static void SaveFile(string text)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter file name with extension: ");
            string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("File saved as " + fileName + ".");
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to open the file? (Y/N)");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input.ToUpper() == "Y")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
                Console.Clear();
            }
            else if (input.ToUpper() == "N")
            {
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

In your `Backspace` routine you don't modify your `text` variable correctly

In this code block:

```
else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && currentPosition > leftMargin)
{
    currentPosition--;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
    if (text.Length > 0)
    {
        text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

You ignore the `currentPosition` and `currentLine` when handling the `text` varialbe and simply remove the last character of the variable.

By doing this your routine of highlightning colors has an undesired value, and you are restoring the old value.

```
foreach (var highlight in highlightColors)
{
    string word = highlight.Key;
    ConsoleColor color = highlight.Value;
    int index = text.IndexOf(word); //<--- value of variable text is wrong
    while (index >= 0)
    {
        int line = topMargin + text.Substring(0, index).Split('\n').Length - 1;
        if (line == currentLine)
        {
            int lineStartIndex = text.LastIndexOf('\n', index) + 1;
            int column = index - lineStartIndex;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(leftMargin + column, currentLine);
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.Write(word); //<--- writes wrong value
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        index = text.IndexOf(word, index + word.Length);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

An attempt to fix your `backspace` routine is

instead of

```
if (text.Length > 0)
{
    text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
}
```

try this

```
if (text.Length > 0)
{
    //try to find the index within the text varialbe based on currentLine and currentPosition

    //split text into lines
    var lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine);

    //get the starting index eg. currentLine is 5, we want to ignore first 4 lines
    var startIndex = lines.Take(currentLine - 1).Sum(x => x.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length);

    //shift startIndex by the currentPosition
    var currentIndex = startIndex + currentPosition;

    //add whitespace, just like Console.Write(" ") did
    text = text.Substring(0, currentIndex) + " " + text.Substring(currentIndex + 1);
}
```

Comment: hello please thank you i am very glad and happy you help me

but i got this error
```
Scripter.cs(132,17): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments
Scripter.cs(132,28): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'
Scripter.cs(135,28): error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no extension method 'Take' accepting a
        first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```

Comment: use this instead `var lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: hello Rand Random do i have to use dot net or new framework because i am just compiling by adding default framework to environment variables path and compiling just by typing csc Scripter.cs in CMD?

Comment: with the original code you would need anything higher then .net core 2.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-2.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions) | you are using .net framework which doesn't offer the overload I originally used | the alternative works in .net framework

Comment: never used `csc scripter.cs`, so I am afraid can't help there only use visual studio to build

Comment: Hello respected sir ,after compilation i added a additional namespace language query and with your help i was able to remove the backspace bug but potentially i m facing new bug

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Comment: sir the backspace bug was removed but i am facing a potential bug please help

Comment: sir the code got a bug

Comment: But you never mentioned what the bug is, I thought (which would be advisable) you will write a new question with the new found bug.