# How to remove the word repeating bug in C#

Tags: c#

I am facing a bug that repeats the word in the CLI and potentially only when I remove syntax highlighted words [Scripter window with words highlighted, one occurring twice, but not in a row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk2UZ.png)
also when I write a syntax highlighting word without any mistakes it highlights but whenever I make mistake it does not PLEASE CHECK OUT THE BUG, I HAVE ALSO ADDED THE VIDEO TO VEED CHECK OUT THROUGH GIVEN LINK [enter link description here](https://www.veed.io/view/bf7e1ec7-fcfa-4c5a-b62f-ef50947ab178?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool isInEditorMode = false; // Track if we are in editor mode
        static Dictionary<string, ConsoleColor> highlightColors = new Dictionary<
            string,
            ConsoleColor
        >();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "SCRIPTER - Version 1.01";
            // Add your desired word-color mappings to the highlightColors dictionary
            highlightColors.Add("<html>", ConsoleColor.DarkBlue);
            highlightColors.Add("</html>", ConsoleColor.DarkBlue);
            highlightColors.Add("<head>", ConsoleColor.Blue);
            highlightColors.Add("</head>", ConsoleColor.Blue);
            highlightColors.Add("<title>", ConsoleColor.Red);
            highlightColors.Add("</title>", ConsoleColor.Red);
            highlightColors.Add("<body>", ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
            highlightColors.Add("</body>", ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
            highlightColors.Add("<table>", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
            highlightColors.Add("</table>", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
            highlightColors.Add("<marquee>", ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
            highlightColors.Add("</marquee>", ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);

            Console.Clear();
            string input;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    @"▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
██░▄▄▄░██░▄▄▀██░▄▄▀█▄░▄██░▄▄░█▄▄░▄▄██░▄▄▄██░▄▄▀███▀███▀█▀░█████░▄▄░█▀░██
██▄▄▄▀▀██░█████░▀▀▄██░███░▀▀░███░████░▄▄▄██░▀▀▄████░▀░███░██▀▀█░▀▄░██░██
██░▀▀▀░██░▀▀▄██░██░█▀░▀██░██████░████░▀▀▀██░██░█████▄███▀░▀█▄▄█░▀▀░█▀░▀█
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀"
                );
                Console.WriteLine(
                    @"
                .---------.
                | samTime |
                '---------'
"
                );

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Enter E to enter editor mode, I to open a file, or Q to quit the program."
                );
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input.ToUpper() == "E")
                {
                    isInEditorMode = true;
                    EditorMode();
                    isInEditorMode = false;
                }
                else if (input.ToUpper() == "I")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the path of the file to open: ");
                    string filePath = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                        isInEditorMode = true;
                        EditorMode(text);
                        isInEditorMode = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine(filePath + " doesnot exist");
                    }
                }
                else if (input.ToUpper() == "Q")
                {
                    break; // Exit the while loop and terminate the program
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void EditorMode(string text = "")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Editor mode. Press Ctrl+S to save, Ctrl+X to exit.");
            int topMargin = Console.CursorTop;
            int leftMargin = Console.CursorLeft;
            int currentLine = topMargin;
            int currentPosition = leftMargin;

            Console.Write(text);
            currentPosition += text.Length;

            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
            do
            {
                keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

                // Check if we are in editor mode before processing the key
                if (isInEditorMode)
                {
                    if (
                        keyInfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control && keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.S
                    )
                    {
                        Console.Clear(); // Clear the console screen
                        SaveFile(text);
                        return; // Exit the EditorMode method
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && currentPosition > leftMargin)
                    {
                        currentPosition--;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                        Console.Write(" ");
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                        
if (text.Length > 0)
{
    //try to find the index within the text varialbe based on currentLine and currentPosition

    //split text into lines
   var lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    //get the starting index eg. currentLine is 5, we want to ignore first 4 lines
    var startIndex = lines.Take(currentLine - 1).Sum(x => x.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length);

    //shift startIndex by the currentPosition
    var currentIndex = startIndex + currentPosition;

    //add whitespace, just like Console.Write(" ") did
    text = text.Substring(0, currentIndex) + " " + text.Substring(currentIndex + 1);
}

                    }
                    else if (
                        keyInfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control && keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.X
                    )
                    {
                        Console.Clear(); // Clear the console screen
                        return; // Exit the EditorMode method
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow && currentPosition > leftMargin)
                    {
                        currentPosition--;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                    }
                    else if (
                        keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow
                        && currentPosition < Console.WindowWidth - 1
                    )
                    {
                        currentPosition++;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && currentLine > topMargin)
                    {
                        currentLine--;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                    }
                    else if (
                        keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow
                        && currentLine < Console.WindowHeight - 1
                    )
                    {
                        currentLine++;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    {
                        text += Environment.NewLine;
                        currentLine++;
                        currentPosition = leftMargin;
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                    }
                    else if (char.IsControl(keyInfo.KeyChar))
                    {
                        // Ignore control characters
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        text += keyInfo.KeyChar;
                        Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
                        currentPosition++;
                    }

                    // Check if any highlighted words are present in the text and apply
                    // the corresponding colors
                    foreach (var highlight in highlightColors)
                    {
                        string word = highlight.Key;
                        ConsoleColor color = highlight.Value;
                        int index = text.IndexOf(word);
                        while (index >= 0)
                        {
                            int line = topMargin + text.Substring(0, index).Split('\n').Length - 1;
                            if (line == currentLine)
                            {
                                int lineStartIndex = text.LastIndexOf('\n', index) + 1;
                                int column = index - lineStartIndex;
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(leftMargin + column, currentLine);
                                Console.ForegroundColor = color;
                                Console.Write(word);
                                Console.ResetColor();
                            }
                            index = text.IndexOf(word, index + word.Length);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(currentPosition, currentLine);
                }
            } while (true);
        }

        static void SaveFile(string text)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter file name with extension: ");
            string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("File saved as " + fileName + ".");
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to open the file? (Y/N)");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input.ToUpper() == "Y")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
                Console.Clear();
            }
            else if (input.ToUpper() == "N")
            {
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Video is not working, but also this code is probably not minimal, reproducible example for this issue.

Comment: thank you sir for your response please check this video https://www.veed.io/view/bf7e1ec7-fcfa-4c5a-b62f-ef50947ab178?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

Comment: please help to fix the bug

Answer (score 1):

Problem is similar to the issue you faced in the previous question

[how to remove backspace key bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440574)

You once again, ignore the `currentLine` and `currentPosition` when handling your `text` variable, this time in the routine of adding a new character.

This code:

```
else
{
    text += keyInfo.KeyChar;
    Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
    currentPosition++;
}
```

Will simply add the `keyInfo.KeyChar` to the very end of `text` regardless where the cursor currently is.

So, similar how the `backspace` got altered you need to know where in the `text` variable to make the necessary change, there for taking the same code to evaluate the index of the previous question (removed the comments, and used the .net framework compatible version of split as was mentioned in the commets)

```
else
{
    //text += keyInfo.KeyChar;
    var lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var startIndex = lines.Take(currentLine - 1).Sum(x => x.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length);
    var currentIndex = startIndex + currentPosition;

    text = text.Substring(0, currentIndex) + keyInfo.KeyChar + text.Substring(currentIndex);

    Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
    currentPosition++;
}
```

**Edit:**

Why does the `backspace` matter?

Because your logic of backspace is add a whitespace with `Console.Write(" ");`, so when you hit the backspace your `text` varialbe changed from `<titi` to `<tit`  (notice whitespace at end) while simultaniously moving the cursor position at `<tit` so when you add new characters your `text` variable will look like this `<tit l` which doesn't match your highlight color keywords.

Comment: should i edit this part of code and is this the part causing the problem ?

else
                    {
                        text += keyInfo.KeyChar;
                        Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
                        currentPosition++;
                    }

Comment: Yes, that is the part causing the problem and yes you can replace the code. edited my answer

Comment: sir i think i should add var lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Comment: yes, noticed. Copy and paste error on my side (already fixed with latest edit)

Comment: nothing I could think of right now, though I would advise checking all occurences of your `text` variable and re-think do hande the current cursor position correctly - there is atleast one place where it still will cause problems in the `else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)` block - but thats all from me for now, I am off to my weekend - bye